# pInvoke in c# (Managed code)

Tags: c++, pinvoke

I am trying to pInvoke a C method in c#, but it is giving error;
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

C Method;

```
HRESULT FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst(
_In_   LPCWSTR lpVolumeName,
_In_   INSTANCE_INFORMATION_CLASS dwInformationClass,
_Out_  LPVOID lpBuffer,
_In_   DWORD dwBufferSize,
_Out_  LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
_Out_  LPHANDLE lpVolumeInstanceFind
);

typedef struct _INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION {
ULONG  NextEntryOffset;
USHORT InstanceNameLength;
USHORT InstanceNameBufferOffset;
} INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PINSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

This is my code

```
  [DllImport("FltLib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]           
        string lpVolumeName,
        _INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION dwInformationClass,
       // IntPtr dwInformationClass,
        out StringBuilder lpBuffer,
        int dwBufferSize,
        out UInt32 lpBytesReturned,
        ref IntPtr lpVolumeInstanceFind);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct _INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public uint NextEntryOffset;
    public uint InstanceNameLength;
    public uint InstanceNameBufferOffset;
}
```

and calling code is;

```
_INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION ins = new _INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION();

            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            uint ret = 512;
            IntPtr vol = new IntPtr(100);

            int res = FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst("H:", ins, out sb1, 516, out ret, ref vol);
```

Please help, 
Thanks

Comment: You need to construct string builder with an explicit size. This might not be your issue but this has bitten me in the rear before.

Comment: @Morphing that won't help because the buffer is not a string and the pinvoke is completely wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your p/invoke translations are wrong. You've got the wrong types in your struct. It should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public uint NextEntryOffset;
    public ushort InstanceNameLength;
    public ushort InstanceNameBufferOffset;
}
```

And the function itself was somewhat off. It should be:

```
[DllImport("FltLib")]
public static extern uint FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]           
    string lpVolumeName,
    uint dwInformationClass,
    out INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer,
    uint dwBufferSize,
    out uint lpBytesReturned,
    out IntPtr lpVolumeInstanceFind
);
```

The information class is really an enum. Look up its value in the appropriate header file. A quick web search suggests that `InstanceBasicInformation` has a value of `0`. Do check that for yourself though by consulting the header file. Pass the size of the struct as `dwBufferSize`.

The call should be along these lines:

```
INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION basicInfo;
uint bytesReturned;
IntPtr volumeInstanceFind;
uint res = FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst("H:", InstanceBasicInformation,
    out basicInfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INSTANCE_BASIC_INFORMATION)), 
    out bytesReturned, volumeInstanceFind);
```

These translations are always easiest done by writing C++ code first. Then you know what a correct call sequence is without being confounded by erroneous p/invoke translation.

Comment: Thanks :) great, its all working after a bit tweet on your provided code.